# How do I produce a fully editable multipage PDF from multiple PSD files in CS5?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, pdf

I have a large number of pages ready as multiple PSD files. I need to make these into at least 2 page PDFs for double sided printing (even better if I can combine them all into one large file), while maintaining full editablitly in Photoshop. I can easily save them as single page PDFs with full editing enabled, but I cannot find a way to combine them without turning them into static images. I have a full CS5 suite to work with. Can anyone tell me how to do this? Alternatively, if this is just not possible at all, can people let me know so I don't waste any more time looking for a method.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible. I'll provide a couple alternative below.

1. Create PDF from multiple PSD files (non-editable)

   - File > automate > pdf presentation
   - Browse for your PSDs
   - Change your settings
   - Click "save"
2. Import your PSDs into Indesign

   - Create new Id Document
   - Place each PSD in a new page
   - Export PDF
   - Both the Indesign doc and PSDs stay editable, but not the pdf

If the printer needs to edit the document its probably best to just package an indesign file and hand that off. That way the printer can edit what they need to then export a pdf for printing

Answer (score 1):

It is traditional for all print production to have working, editable, native files *then flattened PDFs* for production. Few are attempting to do both in one format.

While what you are asking may *seem* logical, it really isn't.

- If you need editable files, then save them as editable, native files.
- If you need production files, then save them as production files. **Don't try and shove everything into one container.**

Save your PSD files as PSD files for editing. Then flatten the files to .tiff and create the PDF needed for production.

<sub>Just my *opinion* but multi-page documents should really *never* be created with Photoshop. There are much better tools for those sorts of documents.</sub>